# How should I send a varray from plsql to java using jdbc?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function that returns a "TYPE varr IS VARRAY(100001) OF VARCHAR2(32000);". Using a callable statement for the function, I want to get this vector into a String[] in Java. How should I do it?

I have tried the following code, but it gives an error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation".

```
    CallableStatement statement=Database.getConnection().prepareCall("{? = call data_mining.return_treshold}");
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
    statement.executeQuery();
    Array arr=statement.getArray(1);
    String[] vec=(String[])arr.getArray();
```

Comment: Have you looked up the ORA-03115 error code for details?

Comment: Yes, still don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the name of the type in the call to `registerOutParameter`:

```
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "VARR");
```

Comment: This is what I get with "VARR" specified.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern

Comment: Note that type `VARR` must be defined using a `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE` statement, not just as a type definition inside a PL/SQL function, procedure, or package.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thank you!! I was not defining varr with CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE outside my package. Now it works.